# Why vector not free objects or what happens anyway?

Tags: c++, vector

I don't understand what happens here! I define class cVtst, and create vector. I watch when the objects are created and destroyed.

```
class cVtst { 
public: 
    int v;
    cVtst(int v) { 
        this->v = v; 
        printf("Creating cVtst %d\n", v); 
    }
    ~cVtst() { 
        printf("Closing cVtst %d\n", v);
    } 
};

std::vector<cVtst> vc;
vc.push_back(34); 
vc.push_back(2); 
vc.push_back(-5);
while (!vc.empty()) vc.pop_back();
```

The result is:

```
Creating cVtst 34
Closing cVtst 34
Creating cVtst 2
Closing cVtst 34
Closing cVtst 2
Creating cVtst -5
Closing cVtst 34
Closing cVtst 2
Closing cVtst -5
Closing cVtst -5
Closing cVtst 2
Closing cVtst 34
```

So ... ?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: You forgot to annotate the copy and move constructors.

Comment: My question is why I don't see what expected:
    Creating cVtst 34
    Creating cVtst 2
    Creating cVtst -5
    Closing cVtst -5
    Closing cVtst 2
    Closing cVtst 34

Comment: Because you forgot to annotate the copy and move constructors. Don't you believe @Mat?

Comment: And there may be more intermediate copies in between. Also, [edit] your question to include all necessary information, don't just comment

Comment: I don't understand Mat & Bathsheba. Write right code, pls!

Comment: You don't understand how a `std::vector` grows. There are copy/move operations you are not seeing.

Comment: Try adding `vc.reserve(3)` after creating the vector and then use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` and then you should get the output you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate your class a little more, and that should make clear what is happening.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

using std::printf;
using std::vector;

class cVtst {
  static int seqCounter;
  int seq;
  int v;
public:
  cVtst(int v) {
    this->v = v;
    this->seq = ++seqCounter;
    printf("Creating cVtst#%d %d\n", seq, v);
  }
  ~cVtst() {
    printf("Closing cVtst#%d %d\n", seq, v);
  }
  cVtst() {
    this->v = ~0 & (~0U >> 1);
    this->seq = ++seqCounter;
    printf("Default Creating cVtst#%d %d\n", seq, v);
  }
  cVtst(cVtst const& other) {
    this->v = other.v;
    this->seq = ++seqCounter;
    printf("Copy Creating cVtst#%d %d\n", seq, v);
  }
};

int cVtst::seqCounter = 0;

int main() {
  vector<cVtst> vc;
  vc.push_back(34);
  vc.push_back(2);
  vc.push_back(-5);
  while (!vc.empty()) vc.pop_back();
}
```

UPDATE:
What your original example isn't taking into account is that the C++ compiler will synthesize a copy constructor and a default constructor.

So your output is not showing those constructors, which is why you are seeing an unbalanced set of Creating and Closing output.  (I assume that your "So...?" question is "Why are they Creating and Closing output unbalanced?")

Comment: You should comment a bit and not only show code.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I need to read more about these constructors. I did not know they existed!